Keycloak-Keycloak SSO
I’m working on two spring boot projects where I am using Keycloak as an authentication provider. I have a requirement to use SSO in my Application. The two applications use  two different keycloaks and these two keycloak should use each other as an identity provider in order to implement SSO.
I’m unable to use keycloak 1 as an identity provider to keyclaok 2.
Can anyone please help me to configure the above in keycloak and which keycloak apis should I use to achieve these.
Also interested to know if we can customize the above flow in Keycloak SPI.
